# Access EF commands in code

Tags: powershell, entity-framework-4, migration

I'm looking to create a console app that spits out a sql script with my updates to the database so i can run this in production/test.

Is there a way of accessing the powershell commands in code?

So I want it to generate my migration files and then a script to update the relevant db i.e. either prod or test. This will be passed in as an argument, so it needs to compare against the prod db or the test db depending on what parameter is passed in.

Comment: This is very unclear.  What exactly are you having trouble with? Creating a text file with powershell?

Comment: So you are creating console application to upgrade database? And what is a difference to running powershell console and executing powershell commands directly?

Comment: I need to hand the app over to support staff, they will run the console app which is part of my solution and it will generate a sql script so all they have to do is run it against the relevant db, basically automating it a bit more. I want to know how to access the powershell commands in c# code. Can i call something like xx.GenerateScript or xx.UpdateDatabase from within my app?

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post shows how to write code that does migrations](http://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/).  The code is C# but if you really want, you should be able to port it to PowerShell.